# How do I fix the method name expected and compiler error on unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first question on stack overflow.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharControl : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public GameObject thePlayer;
    public bool isRunning;
    public float horizontalMove;
    public float verticalMove;
    
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal") || Input.GetButton("Vertical")) 
        {
            thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play()("Run");
            horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150;
            verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 8;
            isRunning = true;
            transform.Rotate(0, horizontalMove, 0);
            transform.Translate(0, 0, verticalMove);
        }
        else
        {
            thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Idle");
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I got a few error messages like

Assets\Scripts\Characters\CharControl.cs(15,13): error CS0149: Method name expected

All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!
UnityEditor.SceneView:ShowCompileErrorNotification ()

I have no idea on how to fix this so I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance.

I just started on a GTA-like series on unity. I'm following the tutorial of Jimmy Vegas. I haven't run into any problems so far. I got a few errors on the coding(C#) part.

Comment: `thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Run");` Remove the extra `()`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja seems likely but, if we had the actual code, like to OP we could tell precisely what code was at  `Assets\Scripts\Characters\CharControl.cs(15,13)` .

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your code.

in the following line:
`thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play()("Run");`

you are trying to call the `Play()` method on the `Animation` component of the `thePlayer` GameObject, but you have not provided a parameter to the method, you just provided empty braces to the `Play()` method, and passed the string inside separate braces after.

try this one:

`thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Run");`

Please be aware that the `Animation` component is deprecated in Unity, and you should consider using the `Animator` component instead.